# How to select element with selenium in python and get the text?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In python I am trying to select this element

```
<button stid="FLIGHTS_DETAILS_AND_FARES-index-1-LDUWT-FlightsActionButton" data-test-id="select-link" data-stid="FLIGHTS_DETAILS_AND_FARES-index-1-LDUWT-FlightsActionButton" class="uitk-card-link" type="button"><span class="is-visually-hidden">Select and show fare information for Etihad Airways flight, departing at 10:50am from Geneva, arriving at 1:05pm in Tokyo, Priced at $2,224 Roundtrip per traveler. Arrives 1 day later. 19 hours 15 minutes total travel time, One stop, Layover for 3 hours 10 minutes in Abu Dhabi.</span></button>
```

and to extract the text. I tried to use the following expression

```
element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@stid='FLIGHTS_DETAILS_AND_FARES-index-1-LDUWT-FlightsActionButton']")
print(element.text)
```

I also tried

```
element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Select and show fare information")]')
print(element.text)
```

which results in an "Unable to locate element" error.

Also the `stid` element might change between calls to the webpage.

Comment: can you share the url if its public

Comment: The URL is public: `https://www.expedia.com/Flights-Search?flight-type=on&mode=search&trip=roundtrip&leg1=from:Geneva%20(GVA%20-%20Cointrin%20Intl.),to:Tokyo%20(TYO%20-%20All%20Airports),departure:8/4/2023TANYT&leg2=from:Tokyo%20(TYO%20-%20All%20Airports),to:Geneva%20(GVA%20-%20Cointrin%20Intl.),departure:8/18/2023TANYT&options=cabinclass:economy&fromDate=8/4/2023&toDate=8/18/2023&d1=2023-8-4&d2=2023-8-18&passengers=adults:1,infantinlap:N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your locators were not correct, i ahve corrected both you have provided above
try any of these below and Extract the text for the span element

#1 Since part of ID is dynamic you can just use contains

```
//button[contains(@stid,'FLIGHTS_DETAILS_AND_FARES')]//span
```

#2 The text element Tag is actually span not button

`//span[contains(text(), "Select and show fare information")]`